# Redirect to index.html when URL contained a potentially malicious String in spring boot

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot

I'm developing an app with spring boot as its backend and angular 6 as its frontend. I build all frontend files to static folder of the spring boot. In all cases whether it be a `(type=Internal Server Error, status=500)` error or `(type=Not Found, status=404)` error, I want my app to not show the "**Whitelabel Error Page**" and instead redirect the user to **index.html** file in the static folder. I could achieve it for 404 error code by adding below code to my **WebMvcConfigurer**:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    //registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**/*")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
                @Override
                protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath,
                                               Resource location) throws IOException {
                    Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
                    return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable() ? requestedResource
                            : new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
                }
            });
}
```

But could not achieve the same result for 500 error code. For example when I type a url with special characters in addressbar, I get this error:

```
**Whitelabel Error Page**

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Tue Oct 23 13:56:11 IRST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String ";"
```

but if I type some wrong url without special character, I'd be redirected the the "index.html" file.
I also tried adding these lines to my **WebMvcConfigurer** but that didn't work either:

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/notFound").setViewName("forward:/static/index.html");
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("forward:/static/index.html");
    registry.addViewController("/error").setViewName("forward:/static/index.html");
}

@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> containerCustomizer() {
    return container -> {
        container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/notFound"));
        container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/error"));
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is not need to more code for this you can create a folder named 'public' in static directory and create directory in this folder named 'error' after that create file named '500.html' or  '404.html' or http_code.html in error directory now you can redirect these files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But I want it to be a one step transition. That you said would be a two step redirect, once user will be redirected to "500.html" and then to the "index.html".